# Check corrupt mysql Database table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to check for corrupt tables in mysql database while it is running. This check will be done in a service which will run continues. I was looking at mysqlcheck, but the documentations says that it locks and unlocks a table. Is mysqlcheck time efficient to use in a service, and if not what is a better approach/

Comment: How often are you encountering corrupt tables in MySQL that this is something you need to continuously monitor for?

Comment: yes it is something i need to continously check for. One corrupt table will affect other components

Comment: No you don't. If corruption happens too frequently for your taste, you'll need to find the reason and address it. If MySQL encounters a corrupted table, it will write a record in the error log; it should be sufficient to monitor that.

Answer (score 1):

I won't answer the question you asked; instead I will try to dissuade you from thinking you need to ask that question.

Do not use MyISAM; it can become corrupt sometimes, (rarely).

Do use InnoDB; it essentially never becomes corrupt, even across nasty crashes.

Do not expect any disk crash to be repairable.  Use other techniques to recover from such.

Bottom line:  mysqlcheck is often needed *for MyISAM* after a power failure.  However, mysqlcheck is both useless and unneeded for InnoDB.

Comment: +1 for crashes *not* being repairable.  If someone crashes their car, they probably wouldn't try to drive that car again straight away - they would get /another/ car that is safe to use.  This is why [we] DBAs make such a "Song and Dance" about keeping /proper/ Backups.